# Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : all arguments must have the same length when run confusionMatrix with caret, in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have an issue running a confusionMatrix.

here is what I do:

```
rf <- caret::train(tested ~., 
                               data = training_data, 
                               method = "rf",
                               trControl = ctrlInside,
                               metric = "ROC", 
                               na.action = na.exclude)

rf
```

After I get my model this is the next step I take:

```
evalResult.rf <- predict(rf, testing_data, type = "prob")
predict_rf <- as.factor(ifelse(evalResult.rf <0.5, "positive", "negative"))
```

And then I am running my confusion matrix.

```
cm_rf_forest <- confusionMatrix(predict_rf, testing_data$tested, "positive")
```

And the error comes after I apply the confusionMatrix:

```
Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Nevertheless, I give you bits of my data.

train data:

```
structure(list(tested = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("negative", "positive"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(63, 23, 28, 40, 31, 60), number_days_symptoms = c(1, 
    1, 16, 1, 14, 1), care_home_worker = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    health_care_worker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), how_unwell = c(1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 
    1), self_diagnosis = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), chills = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    cough = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diarrhoea = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    fatigue = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), headache = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Headcahe", "No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    loss_smell_taste = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), muscle_ache = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    nasal_congestion = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), nausea_vomiting = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    shortness_breath = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), sore_throat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    sputum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), temperature = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("37.5-38", "38.1-39", "39.1-41", 
    "No"), class = "factor"), asthma = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diabetes_type_one = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes_type_two = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    obesity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    heart_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), lung_condition = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    liver_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), kidney_disease = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here is my test_data:

```
structure(list(tested = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("negative", "positive"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(19, 26, 30, 45, 40, 43), number_days_symptoms = c(20, 
    1, 1, 20, 14, 1), care_home_worker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    health_care_worker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), how_unwell = c(7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    2), self_diagnosis = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), chills = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    cough = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diarrhoea = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    fatigue = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), headache = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Headcahe", "No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    loss_smell_taste = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), muscle_ache = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    nasal_congestion = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), nausea_vomiting = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    shortness_breath = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), sore_throat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    sputum = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), temperature = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("37.5-38", "38.1-39", "39.1-41", 
    "No"), class = "factor"), asthma = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diabetes_type_one = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes_type_two = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    obesity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    heart_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), lung_condition = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    liver_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), kidney_disease = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(2L, 
8L, 11L, 14L, 20L, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Additionally, I perform a smote balancing class, on a subsample in ctrInside.

This is my smote function:

```
smotest <- list(name = "SMOTE with more neighbors!",
                func = function (x, y) {
                  115
                  library(DMwR)
                  dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
                  dat$.y <- y
                  dat <- SMOTE(.y ~ ., data = dat, k = 3, perc.over = 100, perc.under =
                                 200)
                  list(x = dat[, !grepl(".y", colnames(dat), fixed = TRUE)],
                       y = dat$.y) },
                first = TRUE)
```

And ctrlInside is this:

```
ctrlInside <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 5,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           savePredictions = TRUE, 
                           search = "grid",
                           sampling = smotest)
```

Those function are given just so that you have an idea of what I am doing per whole. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Hey @GaB, can you check what you have posted, firstly, it is ```evalResult.rf <- predict(rf_tuned, testing_data, type = "prob")``` then ```predict_rf <- as.factor(ifelse(rf_pred<0.5, "positive", "negative"))```, but ```rf_pred``` was not assigned

Comment: then you have ```confusionMatrix(predict_rf, testing_data$Covid_tested, "positive")``` but testing_data has no Covid_tested column

Comment: @StupidWolf - okay - done all the corrections in this post. I have nevertheless corrected in my scripts and still got the same result

Comment: ok then you need to check when there is any NAs in your testing_data, for example, table(complete.cases(testing_data)) and see if any FALSE

Comment: sorry @GaB, if i try running what you have with made up data with the same columns it works. so there must be something in your data, and you needa check that

Comment: @StupidWolf:So, this is probably the reason. I am running the table(complete.cases and the output is: FALSE TRUE 1 12160 What shall I do?

Comment: i looked through again, and posted a more detailed answer on how to solve your problem. Give it a shot and it should work out well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use complete.cases to predict only those that have no nas, also you must operate on the matrix, I will show below. Using an example dataset, I make 10 of the variable in a column NAs, and train:

```
idx = sample(nrow(iris),100)
data = iris
data$Petal.Length[sample(nrow(data),10)] = NA
data$tested = factor(ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor","positive","negative"))
data = data[,-5]
training_data = data[idx,]
testing_data= data[-idx,]

rf <- caret::train(tested ~., data = training_data, 
                              method = "rf",
                              trControl = ctrlInside,
                              metric = "ROC", 
                              na.action = na.exclude)
```

Do the evaluation result and you can see i get the same error:

```
evalResult.rf <- predict(rf, testing_data, type = "prob")
predict_rf <- as.factor(ifelse(evalResult.rf <0.5, "positive", "negative"))
cm_rf_forest <- confusionMatrix(predict_rf, testing_data$tested, "positive") 

Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

So there's two sources of error, 1.. you have NAs and they cannot predict that, and second, evalResult.rf returns a matrix of probabilities, first column is probability being negative class, 2nd being postive:

```
head(evalResult.rf)
   negative positive
3     1.000    0.000
6     1.000    0.000
9     0.948    0.052
12    1.000    0.000
13    0.976    0.024
19    0.998    0.002
```

To get the classes, you do, get the column with max value for each row, and return the corresponding column name, which is the class:

```
colnames(evalResult.rf)[max.col(evalResult.rf)]
```

We do now:

```
testing_data = testing_data[complete.cases(testing_data),]
evalResult.rf <- predict(rf, testing_data, type = "prob")
predict_rf <- factor(colnames(evalResult.rf)[max.col(evalResult.rf)])
cm_rf_forest <- confusionMatrix(predict_rf, testing_data$tested, "positive")

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction negative positive
  negative       33        1
  positive        0       11

               Accuracy : 0.9778          
                 95% CI : (0.8823, 0.9994)
    No Information Rate : 0.7333          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.507e-05       

                  Kappa : 0.9416
```

Comment: it worked! I did this: predict_rf <- factor(colnames(evalResult.rf)[max.col(evalResult.rf)]), after I run a complete.cases on testing data! Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you put SmartWolf :D